# Parsing XML file skip all tags except one with Java

Tags: java, xml, tags

I have one XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE dblp SYSTEM "dblp-2019-11-22.dtd">
<dblp>
<phdthesis mdate="2016-05-04" key="phd/dk/Heine2010">
<author>Carmen Heine</author>
<title>Modell zur Produktion von Online-Hilfen.</title>
<year>2010</year>
<school>Aarhus University</school>
<pages>1-315</pages>
<isbn>978-3-86596-263-8</isbn>
<ee>http://d-nb.info/996064095</ee>
</phdthesis><phdthesis mdate="2020-02-12" key="phd/Hoff2002">
<author>Gerd Hoff</author>
<title>Ein Verfahren zur thematisch spezialisierten Suche im Web und seine Realisierung im Prototypen HomePageSearch</title>
<year>2002</year>  ....(continue to have info about published books.)
```

From that file I want to export only the details about "year" tag. I've tried this code:

```
public class Publications {
    String year1="YEAR";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        {
            try {
                SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
                DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {
                    boolean year = false;

                    //parser starts parsing a specific element inside the document
                    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String year1 , Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
                        System.out.println("Start Element :" + year1);
                        if (year1.equalsIgnoreCase("YEAR")) {
                            year = true;
                        }

                    }

                    //parser ends parsing the specific element inside the document
                    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String year1) throws SAXException {
                        System.out.println("End Element:" + year1);
                    }

                    //reads the text value of the currently parsed element
                    public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {
                        if (year) {
                            System.out.println("Year : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                            year = false;
                        }
                    }
                };
                saxParser.parse("dblp-2020-04-01.xml", handler);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The results I get aren't what I expected to be. It exports more details from all the tags including the year tag.

```
Start Element :ee
End Element:ee
End Element:phdthesis
Start Element :phdthesis
Start Element :author
End Element:author
Start Element :title
End Element:title
Start Element :year
Year : 1990
End Element:year (...)
```

Is there any code suggestion about exporting only the details from "year" tag?

Comment: Do you want to there be only three last lines? if that's true so you can put your print code in if-statement. or you expect something else?

Comment: @SMortezaSA I only want the Year:1990 to appear and all the years after

Comment: Then why you print in `startElement` and `endElement`? if you don't print in these two functions just the `Year : 1990` will be appear. what's the problem?

Comment: Also, as well as what @SMortezaSA mentioned (i.e. comment out the print statements you don't want!), this code has a more subtle problem: the `characters()` method is not guaranteed to read the entire contents of a tag in one pass. See the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ContentHandler.html#characters(char[],%20int,%20int)).

Comment: A `StringBuilder` is generally used to handle this. Keep appending to the string builder until the "end element" event occurs. For short pieces of text such as "1990" you are probably OK - but for longer text (e.g. a synopsis) you may get only part of the data with the above code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Declarative Stream Mapping (DSM)](https://mfatihercik.github.io/dsm) stream parsing library. you can easily define data you want to extract from XML

Here is example mapping for your XML:

```
result:
  path: /dblp/phdthesis/year
  type: array
```

Java code:

```
DSM dsm=new DSMBuilder(new File("path/to/mapping.yaml")).setType(DSMBuilder.TYPE.XML).create();
Object result=  dsm.toObject(xmlFileContent);
// json represntation fo result
dsm.getObjectMapper().writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValue(System.out, object);
```

Result in JSON format:

```
 [ "2010", "2002" ]
```

Working Examle: https://repl.it/@MehmetFatihFat3/DSMFilterData1